# How to connect Mist to a remote private network?

Tags: mist, testnets, network, ipc

I have seen option to connect Mist to a privatenet [here](https://github.com/ethereum/mist#using-mist-with-a-privatenet) like this

```
geth --networkid 1234 --ipcpath /Users/you/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc
```

Looks like the path is hardcoded somewhere in the code.

How can I connect Mist to a private network which is remote?

Comment: Discussion on Meta: [Duplicate or not?](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/244/87)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Looks like the path is hardcoded somewhere in the code.**

Yes. The Mist connections are hard coded to use IPC only, and not RPC.

```
user@Kumquat:~/EthereumSource/mist$ find . -iname '*ipc*'
./tests/mocha-in-browser/spec/ipc-spec.js
./modules/ipc
./modules/ipc/ipcProviderBackend.js
./modules/ipc/ipcProviderWrapper.js
./modules/ipc/getIpcPath.js
./modules/ipcCommunicator.js
user@Kumquat:~/EthereumSource/mist$ find . -iname '*rpc*'
./nodes/eth/darwin-x64/libjsonrpccpp-client.0.dylib
./nodes/eth/darwin-x64/libjsonrpccpp-server.0.dylib
./nodes/eth/darwin-x64/libjsonrpccpp-common.0.dylib
./nodes/eth/darwin-x64/libweb3jsonrpc.dylib
```

And your IPC paths can be found in [modules/ipc/getIpcPath.js lines 7 to 24](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/master/modules/ipc/getIpcPath.js#L7-L24)

```
module.exports = function() {
    var p = require('path');
    var path = global.path.HOME;

    if(process.platform === 'darwin')
        path += '/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc';

    if(process.platform === 'freebsd' ||
       process.platform === 'linux' ||
       process.platform === 'sunos')
        path += '/.ethereum/geth.ipc';

    if(process.platform === 'win32')
        path = '\\\\.\\pipe\\geth.ipc';

    console.log('CONNECT to IPC PATH: '+ path);
    return path;
};
```

Mist and `geth` communicate via IPC by opening a file descriptor on the local computer and then send messages to each other through this file descriptor. So no remote connection currently.

---

**How can i connect Mist to a private network which is remote?**

You could try connecting your local instance of `geth` with your remote `geth` node using the P2P protocol, and then connect Mist to your local `geth` instance using IPC.

In other words, just make your local computer another node in your private network.

You can install a separately installed copy of `geth`, or use the `geth` packaged with Mist which is available in the following directories:

- `{MISTINSTALLDIRECTORY}/resources/node/geth/geth` for Linux and Mac OS X
- `{MISTINSTALLDIRECTORY}\resources\node\geth\geth.exe` for Windows

If your private network has a --networkid {xyz} and a custom genesis file, use the `--networkid {xyz}` and `--genesis {custom genesis file}`.

The next thing is to get your local `geth` to talk to your private network nodes. This will have to be done using `--bootnodes` or creating the files `static-nodes.json` or `trusted nodes` in your data directory. Remember to add `--maxpeers {x}` for a non-zero {x} as omitting this from the command line seems to prevent the connections being made.

Comment: > You could try connecting your local instance of geth with your remote geth node using the P2P protocol, and then connect Mist to your local geth instance using IPC. 

please explain i don't understand it.

Comment: How is your remote private network configured? You could for example create a private network between two separate companies by running `geth` with a  `--networkid {uniqueid}` and `--genesis {custom genesis file}` and have them talking to each other just like how the mainnet Ethereum network communicates through port 30303.

Comment: So it is not possible to connect Mist to remote client, as of now?

Comment: Not from what I've look at in the source code.

Comment: Then just clearly state it in the answer? do you want me to edit?

Comment: I've revised the answer. You are welcome to edit.