# How can I specify an external harddrive as the download target for the Mist blockchain in Ubuntu?

Tags: blockchain, mist, linux, ethereum-wallet-dapp, datadir

How can I specify an external harddrive as the download target for the Mist blockchain?

Hi there,

I am using Linux Ubuntu 15.10

My harddrive is quite full and I need to download the whole Mist blockchain.

Is it possible to specify an external harddrive as the target for the blockchain and if so, how do I do it?

Even if the blockchain data gets corrupted somehow, it won't affect my wallets, right? I can keep them in a folder on my computer instead of the external harddrive, yes or no?

I. e. I would prefer having the blockchain data on an external drive and the wallet files on my laptop harddrive. Possible or not?

Vesa

Answer (score 5):

## Summary

Q: How can I specify an external harddrive as the download target for the Mist blockchain?

A: The answer for the Mac version is in Method 1 in [In Mist browser how can I move the data (blockchain) to another drive on Mac OSX?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3307/in-mist-browser-how-can-i-move-the-data-blockchain-to-another-drive). The Linux version is below.

Q: Even if the blockchain data gets corrupted somehow, it won't affect my wallets, right? I can keep them in a folder on my computer instead of the external harddrive, yes or no?

A: Yes. Just make sure that you backup `~/.ethereum/keystore`.

Q: I. e. I would prefer having the blockchain data on an external drive and the wallet files on my laptop harddrive. Possible or not?

A: Yes.

---

## The Details

The default subdirectory where your Ethereum data files are stored on Linux is `~/.ethereum` .

Within this subdirectory, your blockchain data is stored in the subdirectory `chaindata`, i.e., `~/.ethereum/chaindata` .

Let's assume that your new drive is mounted on `/mnt/extdrive1` for this example.

Copy your `~/.ethereum/chaindata` subdirectory into your new location `/mnt/extdrive1/Ethereum/chaindata` using the following command:

```
mkdir /mnt/extdrive1/Ethereum
cp -rpv ~/.ethereum/chaindata /mnt/extdrive1/Ethereum/
```

A copy of your Ethereum `chaindata` subdirectory will now be located in `/mnt/extdrive1/Ethereum/chaindata`.

Rename your default Ethereum `chaindata` subdirectory for testing:

```
mv ~/.ethereum/chaindata ~/.ethereum/OldChaindata_to_delete_when_tested
```

Soft link your new `chaindata` subdirectory back to the default location:

```
ln -s /mnt/extdrive1/Ethereum/chaindata ~/.ethereum/chaindata
```

Test out your Mist browser and delete your old chaindata directory **ONLY AFTER your testing is successful**:

```
rm -rf ~/.ethereum/OldChaindata_to_delete_when_tested
```

### References

- [In Mist browser how can I move the data (blockchain) to another drive on Mac OSX?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3307/in-mist-browser-how-can-i-move-the-data-blockchain-to-another-drive)
- [ln (Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_%28Unix%29)

Comment: Would this work for Windows, too?

Comment: You should be able to get it working on Windows using the `mklink` command - see http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/?PageSpeed=noscript (I cannot test as I "burned" my Windows OS many moons ago due to the Windows 10 privacy issues). You could try Method 3 in [In Mist browser how can I move the data (blockchain) to another drive on Mac OSX?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3307/in-mist-browser-how-can-i-move-the-data-blockchain-to-another-drive-on-mac-osx) alternatively.

Comment: That worked great, @BokkyPooBah!  For those looking for the code to do this in Windows Vista, 7, 8 or 10: Open command prompt in Windows with administrator privileges, then enter `mklink /J folder_path_that_Mist_looks_at  folder_path_to_your_desired_location`.  In my case with Win8 it looks something like this: `mklink /J C:\User\Username\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum D:\Etherdata\Ethereum`

Comment: The `/J` indicates that you're linking a folder not a file. You do not need to navigate to a particular folder in `command` to do this.

Comment: Excellent. I've added a comment to direct [My C: drive in my windows PC is almost full. How can I change both geth and Mist path to relocate my blockchain files?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3622/my-c-drive-in-my-windows-pc-is-almost-full-how-can-i-change-both-geth-and-mist) to your answer above.