# Extremely slow sync after moving to external drive (macOS; thunderbolt)

Tags: synchronization, storage

I was getting low on disk space so I decided to move the blockchain to an external drive with thunderbolt. I did it using Method 2 from this answer: [In Mist browser how can I move the data (blockchain) to another drive on Mac OSX?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3307/in-mist-browser-how-can-i-move-the-data-blockchain-to-another-drive-on-mac-osx?rq=1)

Now when I start Ethereum Wallet (Mist), the sync is extremely slow. It's been like 5 minutes and I downloaded only about 10 blocks, which is like 20x times slower than when I was downloading to internal drive.

Is there any way to make it go faster? Shouldn't it be downloading directly to the external drive? It's thunderbolt so it should be fast (40GBs), no?

Comment: Is your external storage a HDD? We have issues with that type of drives, only using SSD seems to work for synchronization.

Comment: Oh shoot, it is HDD. Thanks for clarification. Will there be a fix for that any time soon?

Comment: If you search go-ethereum issues in github there are several issues with synchronization and heavy disk i/o, since last year, some of them were fixed but the poor performance remain. From their blog post https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/09/22/transaction-spam-attack-next-steps/ partially the blame is leveldb, but replacing it is a major task. So I do not think it will be fixed very soon. Perhaps after metropolis, but it is a low priority task.